# Algorithm for search multiple value lists c#

Tags: c#, linq, search, arraylist

I have following two lists. Each list contains unique id, message id, reply id. What I want to do is when unique id is given, it's correspondent message id and reply id has to be search in both lists and if a value found same should be happened to that message id or reply id too.

```
List<EmailDetails> inbox_email_details = new List<EmailDetails>();
List<EmailDetails> sent_email_details = new List<EmailDetails>();

public class EmailDetails
{
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    public string ReplyID { get; set; }
}
```

[View Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUt50.png)

if I pass unique id "2" it's MessageID "b" and ReplyID "h" should be searched in both lists. Here "b" have result in 2nd list. Then that result values also should be searched.

I know this is a excruciating task, but is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Can you give us an example for better understanding

Comment: Not exactly getting what you asking.

Comment: What have you already tried? Questions should ask about specific problems, rather not about how "to program this". Your question sounds like "please program my homework" ...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then you are trying to search for particular record from list with `message id`. if that is the case then try with `inbox_email_details.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == messageId);`

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying, you want to search by unique ID, I am considering unique means there will be only one record available in list, If you want to find only one record then you can go with `FirstOrDefault`

```
//OP used 2 as unique ID, I added constant we can use variable as well
    EmailDetails emailDetails = inbox_email_details?.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UniqueID == "2");
```

**This will give instance of EmailDetails with uniqueId = 2, MessageID = b, replyId= h**

Now you want to search with this result, right?

then first check that record is present or not? then use same linq clause

```
   if(emailDetails != null)
    {
       //Here you haven't specifically mentioned search entity
       EmailDetails result = sent_email_details?.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MessageId== emailDetails.MessageId || f.ReplyId == emailDetails.ReplyId);

    }
```

`?` before `.FirstOrDefault` checks list is null or not

Comment: What is `emailDetails` in the null check?

Comment: Or you could do the null check this way `inbox_email_details?.FirstOrDefault...`

Comment: Great effort but it's still unclear what the OP is asking, and BTW `f.UniqueID == '2'` will give compile error because UniqueID is a string not a char

Comment: This answer provides me a headstart. So I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: @ChamaraMadusha, if you could explain your question in more descriptive and easier way then I can help more